# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot when the charger is not connected

Tags: boot, grub2, power-management, thinkpad

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo T495s (with AMD Ryzen in case that matters).

When it is charging, everything is fine.

If I boot while connected to the power and then unplug the power cord, I can continue using it for as long as the battery life allows.

The issue is when the power cord is not connected at the time of the boot. I turn the computer on, get prompted for my disc encryption password and I enter it. Then, it moves on to the next usual step and runs the file checks while saying something along the lines of "Press ctrl-C to cancel the file checks". Everything is the same as booting with a power cord on up to this point. However, after that point, rather then seeing the purple screen that prompts me to select my user and to enter my password, I just get a blank screen. At this point, the computer is still on, but it doesn't seem to move on to anything else from that black screen.

I did a bit a of an online search. Some Dell computers seem to have similar symptoms:

- [Ubuntu budgie 19.10 does not boot on battery power in Dell Precision 7740](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203457/ubuntu-budgie-19-10-does-not-boot-on-battery-power-in-dell-precision-7740)
- https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/m-p/7506203/highlight/true#M3064

Unfortunately, their solution did not work for me.
Any help is appreciated.

heynnema asked for the bios-version:

```
>     $ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
>     R13ET42W(1.16 )
```

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

You have BIOS version R13ET42W(1.16 ).

There's a newer BIOS available, version R13ET44W (1.18 ), dated June 10, 2020, and can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/co/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t495s-type-20qj-20qk/downloads/DS540046) and [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds540046).

**Note**: Please verify that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.